# How do I deal with the git workflow when there are small changes between the developing branch and the production branch?

Tags: python, git, version-control

Currently, I have two branches, say "dev" and "prod". When I'm making changes, I make changes to dev and when it is ready for production, I make the same changes to prod. However, there are some differences between these two branches that I want to keep. For example, I have some code that saves to a database commented out on dev so that I can test it without worrying about affecting anything. I also have a few variables that are different in dev compared to prod. For example:

**dev**

```
file = "dev.csv"

"""
Code that does stuff
"""

# uploadToDatabase(data)
```

**prod**

```
file = "prod.csv"

"""
Code that does stuff
"""

uploadToDatabase(data)
```

Right now, after I commit my changes to dev, I manually update prod with these changes (using PyCharm's compare diff with working tree feature) without adding the dev specific differences.

How can I do this in a more efficient (and correct) way?

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is often handled by a process called a "transform." In this scenario, I am guessing it is better applied in the release (CD) side of the pipeline. There are also build side transforms. Transforms are pretty common. With the little information I have here, I would say that it would probably fit. There are build step handlers for most transform purposes. You will just need to find one that is ideal for your platform.